# Use Gmail-API in multiple computers

Tags: android, api, gmail, gmail-api

I am using the Gmail-API for an app I have been developing a long time. To access the API, I am using a SHA1 fingerprint but that only allows one computer to access the API. How can I make any computer or phone running my app access my API?

***EDIT:*** Can I use the API_KEY?

***EDIT:*** I was wondering how I even go public in a Gmail API Application.

Comment: Are you talking about YOUR API not Google's API?

Comment: No. I'm talking about Google's API.